# Ms access 2010, XML

Tags: ms-access, xslt

I have created a xslt file which transform data thats been exported from mc access as XML.

When the data is exported in a xml format, the data is shown like this:

```
    <StudentDetails>
        <StudentNumber>0112142</StudentNumber>
        <SiteCode>01</SiteCode>
    </StudentDetails>
```

In the transform file I have coded it as the following code and the output is shown above

```
<StudentDetails>
        <xsl:element name="StudentNumber"><xsl:value-of select="StudentNumber"/></xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="SiteCode"><xsl:value-of select="SiteCode"/></xsl:element>    
</StudentDetails>
```

However I want the output to show like this:

```
<StudentDetails>
    <StudentNumber extension="0112142"/>
    <SiteCode extension="01"/>
</StudentDetails>
```

How do i change my transoform code to output the data like the one shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are in the context of `StudentDetails`, you could do:

```
<StudentDetails>
    <StudentNumber extension="{StudentNumber}"/>
    <SiteCode extension="{SiteCode}"/>
</StudentDetails>
```

---

Read about [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates) to understand how this works.